# How to send a Login Intent to Facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an android app where i have both the email-id and password of a Facebook account. How do I send an intent so that it launches the Facebook app and already fill in the email-id and password fields ?

Comment: you need to facebook integration in android app.. try this..

Comment: How can i do that ?

Comment: follow this tutorial.................http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-facebook-integration-tutorial